# Is it possible to open Jetbrains projects with url, e.g. `webstorm://<path_to_project>`

Tags: macos, url

For open content in same topics quickly, I write a list, which works well in `MarginNote`, web links and opening Jetbrains apps. However, I cannot find a document about parameters of `webstorm://...` url? Is it possible to open projects with URL?

list demo:
[image: list demo]

Answer (score 0):

Toolbox URL can do it (Note: [Jetbrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/toolbox/) is required
). For example:

```
jetbrains://web-storm/navigate/reference?project=demo&path=src/lib/Card.svelte
```

You can copy it following the image: [copy steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3vTR.png)

Or make yourself url by edit:

```
jetbrains://<app_name>/navigate/reference?project=<project_name>&path=<path_name>
```

- `app_name` can be `idea`、`pycharm` and so on;
- `&path=<path_name>` is optional.

Now I can open it from my list.